Array Math to Calculate Ice Thickness -- Need Help Simplifying
I posted this on Stack but since it's working code, it was suggested I post it here. I wrote this code to calculate ice thickness using the following equation from Stephenson, 2011.

It's a daily calculation but it uses inputs from both the current day and the day before (since you need to add new ice to the previous depth). If it just used the current day, I would've done regular array math but since it involves a previous-day input, this was how I could best think of doing the math. I know it's incredibly overcomplicated, though, and it takes about 25 minutes to run for one file and I need to run at least four.
Here's the code below (for reference "fdd" and "snd" are the Freezing Degree Days and Snow Depth netcdfs after I open them with xarray). I'll include a zip of the input files if anyone wants to see them but I'd really just appreciate any ideas on how to simplify this code and especially make it faster. I'm sure there's a better way to do it that I just haven't learned yet.
def IceThickness(fdd, snd):
  fdd['fdd'] = fdd['fdd'].fillna(0)
  snd['snw'] = snd['snw'].fillna(0)
  fdd = fdd['fdd'].values
  snd = snd['snw'].values

  # Create a copy of fdd and prepare the ice_thick array
  ice = fdd.drop_vars(['lat_bnds', 'lon_bnds']).rename({"fdd": "ice_thick"}).copy()
  ice.attrs = {}
  ice['ice_thick'].values[:] = 0  # Initialize ice_thick with zeros

  # Assign variables
  Ki = 2.21   # Thermal conductivity of ice
  Ks = .15    # Thermal conductivity of snow
  yi = 917    # Density of ice
  L = 333.4   # Latent heat of ice

  # Iterate through pixels
  for row in range(54):
    for column in range(288):
      h0 = 0    # day -1 of ice is 0
      for day in range(365):
        S = fdd[day, row, column] # Freezing Degree Days for Day i
        hs = snd[day, row, column] # Snow Depth on Day i

        # Calculate ice thickness on Day i
        hi = sqrt((h0 + hs*(Ki/Ks))**2 + ((2*Ki)/(yi*L))*S) - (Ki/Ks)*hs
        ice['ice_thick'][day, row, column] = hi

        h0 = hi   # Set ice_thick on Day 0 to current value

  return ice 

And here is the zip: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1T73ZP6_Q4Xj261haqAjrtkRsslNypPnn/view?usp=sharing

IMHO, a link, as a code comment, to the equation is deserved.

Thank you for citing your reference.
That \$hs\$ snow depth figure seems like quite the wildcard,
since snow can be wet or it can be fluffy.
I wonder if some folks normalize for that by
taking a core and reporting mm of snow meltwater.
docstring
def IceThickness(fdd, snd):

In the Review Context you helpfully explained
what those parameters are all about, thank you.
We really need an explanation in a """docstring""" here, please.
And you could better explain the shape of those two,
either with an English sentence or ideally with type annotations.
While you're at it, might as well annotate this signature
so we also know what return ice is all about.
Maybe there's a NOAA or weather site which describes your xarray
that you'd like to cite?
Including this function's production caller,
or its unit test caller,
would help to shed light on the input params.
Also, pep-8
asked you nicely to name this ice_thickness.
As written it looks like a ClassName.
(I totally give you a pass on names like Ki,
as they are helpfully adhering to the math conventions
of the cited reference.)
new concept, new name
Uggh! I get the temptation, but please try to avoid doing this.
  fdd = fdd['fdd'].values
  snd = snd['snw'].values

fdd meant one thing when the caller passed it in,
and now it means something quite different, it has a different shape.
Please pick a new name for one or the other.
Please run your source code through
$ black *.py
so it is more legible and less susceptible to indent typos.
Two space indents works for JS,
but python folks really expect four.
magic numbers
  for row in range(54):
      for column in range(288):

I'm a little bit sad that we're not picking up these two figures
from fdd.shape.
Also, I would have greater confidence in this code if near the top
we had done assert fdd.shape == snd.shape.
I think that is true, but it's better to know that it is.
row major
  for row in ...
    for column in ...
      for day in ...
        S = fdd[day, row, column]

At least with code written in {C, rust, fortran}
we definitely try to avoid a stride like that.
Better to rip through memory sequentially, just like memcpy() does.
So it would be most natural to have day iterate as
the outermost loop.
Python bytecode is on the slow side,
so maybe it wouldn't show quite so pronounced
the benchmark effect that it would with C.
I just note it in passing,
since your data vendor supplied the data in inconvenient order.
Clearly you need to start with \$h_0\$ and iterate from there.
Though if we make numpy do most of the looping, then yes!
We can loop with day outermost, making 365 numpy calls.
Instead of that h0 = 0 assignment,
initialize all of ice['ice_thick'][day, :, :] to np.zero().
And then S and hs become 54×288 matrices for current day,
and the hi calculation switches from scalar to matrix,
showing each day's ice accumulation across the whole region.
Let us know how it goes!
test suite
This submission lacked
automated tests,
and it needs some.
Write a test which "locks in" the current calculation.
Then refactor the hi calculation, and
write a new test for this new risky code.
Keep working on it until it matches the old calculation,
at least within \$\epsilon\$.
numba
After you add some type annotation,
the (non-vectorized) original OP code
seems to be a fair candidate for JIT compilation.
However, if you can make the numpy approach work, I predict the
BLAS
library code will blow the doors off anything else,
even if we have to ask for 365 loops of bytecode interpretation
to make those numpy calls.

This codebase is clearly written and achieves its design goals.
I would be willing to delegate or accept maintenance tasks on it.
